# How to read separate Excel sheets into separate DataFrames?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file with 13 tabs, and I want to write a function that takes specified sheets from the file, converts them into separate DataFrames, then bundles them into a list of DataFrames. In this case, I want to take the sheets labeled 'tblProviderDetails', 'tblSubmissionStatus', and 'Data Validation Ref Data', convert them into DataFrames and make a list. The reason I want the dfs in a list, is because I want to eventually want to take the input dfs and return a dictionary which will then be used to create a YAML file.

This is ultimately what I want:

```
dfs = [ 'tblProviderDetails', 'tblSubmissionStatus', 'Data Validation Ref Data']
```

The reason that I want to use a user-defined function is that I want the flexibility to call any sheet and any number of sheets into a list.

I was able to write a function that converts single specified sheets to dataframes, but I'm not sure how to call any number of sheets in the Excel file or create a list within the function. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
def read_excel(path, sheet_name, header):
    dfs = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=header)
    return dfs

df1 = read_excel(path=BASEDIR, sheet_name='tblProviderDetails', header=2)
df2 = read_excel(path=BASEDIR, sheet_name='tblSubmissionStatus', header=2)
df3 = read_excel(path=BASEDIR, sheet_name='Data Validation Ref Data', header=2)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this but perhaps the simplest way is to first get all the sheet names and then in a loop for every sheet name, load the result in a data frame and append it to the required list.

```
dfList = []
def read_excel(path, h):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)

    # Now you can access all sheetnames in the file
    sheetsList = xls.sheet_names
    # ['sheet1', 'sheet2', ...]

    for sheet in sheetsList:
        dfList.append(pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet, header 
        =h))
read_excel('book.xlsx',2)
print(dfList)
```

Comment: How do you call specific Excel sheets? Would I add these lines inside of the function above? Sorry, it's still a little unclear

Comment: Edited answer, check again.

Comment: The above code will automatically read all the excel sheets in an excel file, convert them to data frames and add them all to a list of data frames, which I believe is what you asked for.

Comment: The argument 'sheet_name' in pd.read_excel can be used for multiple sheets by passing a  list of the specific sheets u want to to use. In your case it will be  sheet_name =[ 'tblProviderDetails', 'tblSubmissionStatus', 'Data Validation Ref Data'].

Comment: @umar I don't want it to automatically read all the sheets. I want the function to be able to read any combination of sheets. In this case, I want the sheet names to be: 'tblProviderDetails', 'tblSubmissionStatus', 'Data Validation Ref Data'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the a list of sheet names and\or sheet number to parameter sheet_name.

```
def read_excel(path, sheet_name, header):
    sheet_name = ['tblProviderDetails','tblSubmissionStatus','Data Validation 
    Ref Data']
    dfs = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=header)
    return dfs
```

Comment: Can I pass the list of sheet names outside of the function and during the call? i.e. `read_excel(BASEDIR, sheet_name = ['tblProviderDetails','tblSubmissionStatus','Data Validation Ref Data'], header=2)` and leave the sheet_name inside the function as an empty list `sheet_name=[]`

Comment: I presume ur BASEDIR is the same for all sheets so there is no need to to have df1,df2 etc. having the list of sheets inside or outside the function should work either ways. What will be returned is a dataframe of the specified sheet names.

Comment: BASEDIR is the file path for the excel file. If I add the sheet names inside of the function call and print the output, I get `OrderedDict()`. But when the sheet names are inside of the function and I remove the `sheet_name` parameter the output looks correct. The reason I want the ability to add the sheet names to the function call is for added flexibility/usability, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You should explain in your answer what your code does in more detail